# How to upload large files from HDFS to S3

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, hdfs

I have an issue while uploading a large file (larger than 5GB) from HDFS to S3. Is there a way to upload the file directly from HDFS to S3 without downloading it to the local file system and using multipart ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For copying data between HDFS and S3, you should use `s3DistCp`. `s3DistCp` is optimized for AWS and does an efficient copy of large number of files in parallel across S3 buckets.

For usage of `s3DistCp`, you can refer the document here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/UsingEMR_s3distcp.html

The code for `s3DistCp` is available here: https://github.com/libin/s3distcp

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Hadoop 2.7.1 or later, use the s3a:// filesystem to talk to S3. It supports multi-part uploads, which is what you need here.

Update: September 2016

I should add that we are reworking the S3A output stream work for Hadoop 2.8; the current one buffers multipart uploads in the Heap, and falls over when you are generating bulk data faster than your network can push to s3.

Comment: The later part of this answer is pretty catastrophic problem when it comes to uploads.

Comment: yes, which is why you should only use the fast output stream in Hadoop 2.8+, with the default store of disk, unless you are confident that switching to bytebuffer (off heap JVM) or bytearray (on heap) is better. Since I made that comment in 2016, we've removed the older output stream and mandate the fast one. We've not found any bugs in it since the 2.8.0 release. This makes us happy